# How to delete all the files which uploaded 2 days before from SFTP server using java?

Tags: java

```
String sftpUri = "sftp://" + hostname+ ":" + password + "@"
                        + serverHost + filepath;
org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileObject remoteFile = manager.resolveFile(sftpUri+ FileName, opts);
remoteFile.delete();
```

Here I am deleting the files using the file name but this is not enough because in some case i don't have file name. Can somebody help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of `FileObject#findFiles()` to loop over a set of files and recurse, and `SftpFileObject#doGetLastModifiedTime()` to compare the last modification time stamp to the current system time.

Reference:

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-vfs/apidocs/org/apache/commons/vfs2/FileObject.html#findFiles(org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSelector)

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-vfs/apidocs/org/apache/commons/vfs2/provider/sftp/SftpFileObject.html#doGetLastModifiedTime()